# Oracle sequence not updated when using rails seeds file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, oci8

Here's a part of a seeds file I have

```
   Country.create(id: 1, name: 'Turkey', 'description' : 'Gobble gobble')
   Country.create(id: 2, name: 'Hungary', 'description' : 'Blah blah blah')
```

There are two records for these in the countries table after this has run.

So now through the web interface or via an API I try to create a new country and I get the following error from Oracle:

```
OCIError: ORA-00001: unique constraint
```

The constraint is on the primary key.  After seeding, the next two records it attempts to create with id's 1, 2 but they already exist.

I don't understand why when creating the `Country` by seeding with the same code as in the controller/model through an API or web interface I get a different result.

If I alter the sequence through SQLDeveloper with the following snippet, everything works fine:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE countries_seq INCREMENT BY 100;
select countries_seq from dual;
ALTER SEQUENCE countries_seq INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Note this is happening for all models, I'm just using `Country` as an example.

I'm using

```
Ruby 2.1.0
Rails 4.0.5
oracle-enhanced 1.5.5 gem
ruby-oci8 2.1.7 gem
```

**EDIT**

If I don't put id in the create arguments, everything works fine.

```
   Country.create(name: 'Turkey', 'description' : 'Gobble gobble')
   Country.create(name: 'Hungary', 'description' : 'Blah blah blah')
```

It'd be great to know *why* though...

Comment: I don't know what Country.create does, most probably: If you don't assign an id yourself it will be set by the create function or database side by a trigger. You could check the tabledefinition for a trigger.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm missing it but where are you calling `countries_seq.nextval`?

Comment: @evilive I think you're right.  When I provide the id the sequence isn't incremented.  If you put that as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Country.create does, most probably: If you don't assign an id yourself it will be set by the create function or database side by a trigger. You could check the tabledefinition for a trigger.